# Parsing html with lxml on python

Tags: python, html-parsing, lxml

I have following html code:

```
<div class="test">
    "Test"
    <br>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    <a href="mailto:asdf@adsf.com">asdf@adsf.com</a> 
    " "
</div>
```

How to get the email address from this code using lxml?

Answer (score 4):

```
import lxml.html as LH
text='''\
<div class="test">
    "Test"
    <br>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    <a href="mailto:asdf@adsf.com">asdf@adsf.com</a> 
    " "
</div>
'''

doc=LH.fromstring(text)
print(doc.xpath('//a[starts-with(@href,"mailto:")]/text()')[0])
# asdf@adsf.com
```

Comment: <div class="test">
    "Test"
    <br>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    <a href="mailto:asdf@adsf.com">asdf@adsf.com</a> 
    " "
</div> - it necessarily?

Comment: No, it's only used to provide an input for the function. You'll have to replace `text` with whatever you keep the HTML in.